# Definite integral problem. Why is this incorrect?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{\sqrt{4-x}}dx=$$
I used a substitution like so: $t=x^{2}$, and got to 
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{4-\sqrt{t}}}=\frac{1}{2}\left (\arcsin\frac{\sqrt[4]{1}}{2}-\arcsin\frac{\sqrt[4]{0}}{2}  \right )=\frac{\pi }{12}$$
But the correct answer is doing a different substitution: $t=4-x$  and it ends up with this value- $$-6\sqrt{3}+10\tfrac{2}{3}$$

Notice the two answers are very close - mine is $\sim 0.26$ and the other is $\sim 0.27$.

Was my way wrong? If so, why?

Comment: How did you take the definite integral after you substituted for x?

Comment: @Starfall Indeed, I think that there is where the OP made his mistake. He is mistaken, actually, and Wolframalpha can verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derivative of $\arcsin\frac{\sqrt[4]{x}}{2}$ is not $\frac{1}{\sqrt[]{4-\sqrt[]{x}}}$

Answer (score 0):

Put $t:=4-x\implies dx=-dt\;$ , so

$$\int_0^1\frac x{\sqrt{4-x}}dx=\int_4^3\frac{4-t}{\sqrt t}(-dt)=4\int_3^4 t^{-1/2}dt-\int_3^4 t^{1/2}dt=$$

$$=\left.8t^{1/2}\right|_3^4-\left.\frac23t^{3/2}\right|_3^4=8(2-\sqrt3)-\frac23(8-3\sqrt3)=\frac{32}3-6\sqrt3$$